# JQuery FullCalendar Pop up List

Tags: jquery, listview, drop-down-menu, popup, fullcalendar

I want to be able to click on a date in Fullcalendar and pop a list of available start times for a user to select. This can be a drop down or a scrollable list times, but it needs to be selectable and I need to capture that information- Date and Time selected.

Does anyone know of a tool that may be useful? I would prefer to just create a container that is populated by an array and have those times be selectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all your data in the event object sent to calendar. The event data object can contain any data beyond that needed for calendar event

Use the API eventClick method to access your data for that event. You can get the position of the event element using jQuery offset() method. All you will need then is parse data to whatever html you want and create handlers for user interction

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/

Comment: Updated with what i have. Not currently using an event object since this is for a demo design. I may have changed my question a little bit, but hopefully you may have a solution. Cant get the option to carry over for some reason...

Comment: sorry you seemed to have switched gears and not sure what issue is. Not easy to manage whole change of topic in these comment boxes especially now topic seems different

Comment: No worries. Thought I'd ask. Thanks for the prior suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a tooltip plugin like http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/ in addition to what @charlietfl has suggested to achieve your goal.